# Back button on ui appears until you hit options and back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

New to coding here, setting up a UI in unity and having a visual issue where the back button appears until I hit options and back on the start up page, any reccomendations for a fix?
[Image showing back button behind the quit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoRql.jpg)

[Settings of the image on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RdGk.png)

Comment: Can you show the script component under the `OptionsButton` object?

Comment: I used to same script for the option button, not sure if thats what causes the problem

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MNhkFCy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gameobject.setactive(true/false)` and try to manage the panel by making empty game object inside UI Canvas and name it as a panel so the whole button became a child and you can easily manage it

for example like this one

```
public Gameobject startPanel;
public Gameobject optionPanel;

public void Startpnl()
{
  //deadActive optionPanel and Activate startPanel
  startPanel.setActive(true);
  optionPanel.setActive(false);
}

public void optionpnl()
{
  //deadActive starPanel and Activate OptionPanel
  startPanel.setActive(false);
  optionPanel.setActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I keep recieving namespace errors, is it because Gameobject isn't in a method?
I cant seem to solve the issue because im new at coding.

Comment: make sure you add on top `using UnityEngine;` and you can learn about UI here :

`[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8ac_qUXQY)`